# result of logical operation ((0x5C0 & 0x3C0) >> 6) in tcl

Tags: tcl

what is the value of expression in `tcl`  :-

```
((0x5C0 & 0x3C0) >> 6)
```

and how to calculate same formula in `tcl` ?

Comment: Did you try to use the `expr` command yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
set result [expr {(0x5C0 & 0x3C0) >> 6}]
puts $result ;# output 7
```

Read Documentation: [expr](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm)

Comment: When writing examples with `expr`, always follow good practice and brace the expression into a single, non-substituted argument.